# Combine multiple vi-copy mode commands into one command

Tags: vim, vi, tmux

I would like to have a command in tmux vi-copy mode, which combines the following three steps into one:

1. selects the current line
2. copies the selection that was made in step 1
3. copy-pipes the copied selection to xargs

Could it look like this?

```
bind-key -t vi-copy o select-line; copy-selection; copy-pipe "xargs -I{} tmux select-pane -t 1"
```

I got the last part running like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404267/tmux-how-to-open-file-under-cursor):

```
bind -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "xargs -I{} tmux send-keys -t 1 ';call OpenTestFile(\"{}\")' Enter"
```

If I select something in copy mode with the above, tmux is:

1. copying the selection
2. sending the keys: `;call OpenTestFile("SELECTION")` to the pane number 1 (I have vim opened there)
3. switching to that pane

In the vim-function `OpenTestFile(input)` I realize, that vim extracts a filepath from the tmux-line-selection and opens it for editing.

But I don't want to use the `y` key, instead I want to use the `o` key, for doing that and to avoid to having to select the line before.

## Update 1

It seems, that it isn't possible to bind multiple commands in a mode. [link](http://tmux-users.narkive.com/9hgrusmu/can-t-bind-multiple-commands-with-bind-t)

Answer (score 3):

Original tmux doesn't allow to bind more than one command for 'mode' keystrokes.

Luckily, there's a mod for allowing to do that:
http://ershov.github.io/tmux/

For example:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy o tcl { select-line; copy-selection; copy-pipe "xargs -I{} tmux select-pane -t 1" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this specific configuration, but in general you should be able to execute multiple commands inside one binding by backslash-escaping the `;` separator. You can also backslash-escape newlines, so something like this ought to work (assuming your cited example is working):

```
bind -t vi-copy y \
    copy-selection \;\
    copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i" \;\
    copy-pipe "xargs -I{} tmux send-keys -t 1 ';call OpenTestFile(\"{}\")' Enter"
```

Comment: hey, thx for your reply. but i need it like that: ```bind -t vi-copy o select-line \; copy-selection``` if i write it like that, i got a message: ```.tmux.conf:132: not enough arguments```